# TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined when I run via Atom

Tags: javascript

I cloned the code from github and run it via Atom. But the error thrown.
the open source is udemy-downloader-gui

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

at Object. (C:\Users\sbai\github\git1\index.js:88:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```